# How is shorthand Regex syntax different than long version?

Tags: java, regex, shorthand

I'm a beginner programmer in Java and regular expressions, and I wanted to create a simple wordcount program.

I had some trouble with the second example below, and I switched to the first one, and it worked. The second one kept on matching the same word over and over (infinitely, so the rest of the program would not finish), but the first one worked right and counted all the words. I don't know why. I thought that they should be the same.

Given that `line` is an line read from another file to be wordcounted, `word` is a `Pattern` to separate the words, and `wordList` is a `List<String>` that contains all the words, then how is the following code:

```
Matcher match = word.matcher(line);
while(match.find())
    wordList.add(match.group());
```

... different from this code?

```
while((Matcher match = word.matcher(line)).find())
    wordList.add(match.group());
```

Thanks for any help.

(Also, can you help me with the title? I don't know what to call the "shorthand" code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code like

```
while(condition){
    body
}
```

before each iteration code from `condition` is executed to check if `{body}` block should be executed. In case of second example

```
while((Matcher match = word.matcher(line)).find())
    wordList.add(match.group());
```

before each iteration you are executing

```
(Matcher match = word.matcher(line)).find()
```

which creates new `Matcher` instance. What is important here is that these new instances are always set to some default state. In case of Matcher class this state contains information that it should start starting match from start of passed string (in your case `line`) so each of these new created matches can only find first match.

In your first example

```
Matcher match = word.matcher(line);
while(match.find())
    wordList.add(match.group());
```

this problem doesn't exist because you are using only *one instance* of Matcher, which after each `find` remembers position of last found element and will search for next one after this position.

Comment: totally makes sense. Thank you! I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: kind of off topic, but is there a name for combining the `Matcher` declaration and `while` loop statements? it's new to me, and I think it's cool, but i don't know what to call it.

Comment: @Jon If there is then I am not aware of it. It can be described simply as "declaring [something] in while condition" so I don't see any reason to give it a some special name (but I may be wrong).